Camera not found - Microsost Surface Book 2
I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS over Windows 11 on my Microsoft Surface Book 2 laptop & the camera is not recognized.
THINGS I TRIED:

When I searched help, it appeared it to possibly be related to a Kernel issue. Mine is Linux 6.8.0-31-generic.

Another help question made it sound as if the issue wasn't in Firefox. But I am not able to get the camera app to work, or get the camera to work in google meet in Chromium, Firefox or Chrome.

Another answer recommended restarting pipeware & even though I tried to follow the instructions, I don't think I did that correctly & suspect that either that answer is obsolete or I'm missing something.

Another help answer recommended disabling & re-enabling the camera in Bios. I tried that & it did nothing.


UPDATE: I recently found this & it appears to confirm that the front & back cameras are supported for Surface Book 2, but I still wasn't able to figure out what to do to get mine to work. https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Camera-Support
Can anyone help me to get my camera to work?

Please open an issue at GitHub https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues

Thanks - done: https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/1468
